# How to make unique ID for every Item from JSON in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making web shop, and I have such problem:

When I add the same items to cart, they have the same id and when I tried to delete one of them, everything is deleted.

And also I have an error "Keys should be unique..."

So how to make unique id for every Item?

```
{purchases.map(p => <ShoppingCartItem key={p.id} body={p.body} removeItem={() => removeItem(p.id)}/>)}
```

Reducer:

```
        case ADD_ITEM_TO_CART: {
            return {
                ...state,
                shoppingCart:  [...state.shoppingCart, action.phone]
            }
        }
```

State:

```
const initialState = {
   data: phones, // phones - contain all data from JSON
   shoppingCart: []
};
```

JSON has this sructure:

```
{   
        "id": "iPhone-11",
        "body": {
            "section": "phone",
            "model": "iPhone 11",
            "price": "399",
            "description": []
}
```

State: 
[image]

Comment: It seems like p.id is not unique?

Comment: @wentjun yes, because in JSON file I indicated id. So logically when you add the same items, they have the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index as the key. But don't use it as an integer, rather as a string.

```
{purchases.map((p, index) => <ShoppingCartItem key={index.toString()} body={p.body} removeItem={() => removeItem(p.id)}/>)}
```

I would suggest this approach if you are going to use that ID globally in you app (for example, saving it in the DB). Other than that, you can also try using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

As I can see from your question edits, you are adding the content of the JSON directly to the shopping cart. Before adding content, you should modify it's ID or add some extra ID property that will be used only for that purpose. To achieve this, you could do something like this:

```
// Set this counter on the top of the reducer file or in some other file
const TEMPORARY_ID = 0; 

case ADD_ITEM_TO_CART: {
  return {
    ...state,
    shoppingCart:  [
      ...state.shoppingCart, 
      {
        ...action.phone,
        id: `${action.phone.id}-${TEMPORARY_ID++}` //instead of this, I use small library 'shortid'
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem.. I added my reducer's logic, maybe you can help me there..

Comment: @HamzaKhattabi yes, I did it, console error dissapeared, but my main proble that all items have the same id...

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are duplicated entries of `id` from the `purchases` array.

You can either fix the source (probably from the backend) to ensure that the `id`s are unique, or you can fix it on the frontend by ensuring that the keys are unique.

While you can use the index of the array as the `key`, I would not recommend you to solely rely on it.

A more fail-safe way of doing so would be to append the index of each array to the `id`.

```
{purchases.map((p, index) => <ShoppingCartItem key={`${p.id}${index}`} body={p.body} removeItem={() => removeItem(p.id)}/>)}
```

And for the `removeItem` method, I am guessing you will need to edit the logic such that it will handle the removal of items will work if there are multiple items of the same type/`id`.

---

2nd question - removal of items from redux.

Given that you can the redux store can consist of multiple objects of the same `id`, and removal of the single object by referencing the `id` (such as using `Array.filter()`) will not work, as it will simply remove all of the objects with that `id`.

The simplest way without making drastic changes to the data structure would be to remove the object by its index. However, this is assuming that you aren't doing any other modifications (such as sorting) to the array/state before displaying it on the front end.

First and foremost, instead of passing the id, you can pass the index to the `removeItem` method handler.

```
{purchases.map((p, index) => <ShoppingCartItem key={`${p.id}${index}`} body={p.body} removeItem={() => removeItem(index)}/>)
```

And then, on the reducer.

```
case REMOVE_ITEM_FROM_CARD: {
  return {
    ...state,
    shoppingCart: state.shoppingCart.filter((item, index) => index !== action.index
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same proble.. I added my reducer's logic, maybe you can help me there..

Comment: If the user removes the item, the state only only remove the particular item, instead of all items of the same type, right? One quick way to solve this issue would be to remove using the index instead?

Comment: For example, I aded 4 models of "IphoneX", in JSON they have id "Iphone-X", so when I tried to delete one of them from Array, everything is deleted but not only one of them.

Comment: I added photo from state, when I added some of Items.

Comment: Ok got it. Just to check, is it the reducer that handles the logic for removing objects?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but answer aboveis more suitable for me. :)